# Redux : reset 1 variable to initial state in Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a app I'm using redux to manage state, I want to clear the state of only 1 variable to initial state .

> I need to make the new albums state to initial state only that not
>   others , if anyone know please let me know

```
export default {
  loading: true,
  error: null,
  albums: [],
  page: 1,
  lastId: '',
  totalRecord: 0,
  album: {
    loading: true,
    error: null,
    message: null,
    album: null,
  },
  newAlbum: {
    album_id: null,
    images: [],
    totalImages: 0,
    currently_uploading: 0,
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add this case to your reducer:

```
case 'CLEAR_NEW_ALBUM':
  return { ...state, newAlbum: INITIAL_STATE.newAlbum }
```